# KDB: failed to load TLS certificates

Tags: ssl, kdb

when trying to load a q instance with TLS support with 'q -E 1 -p 65000' on linux I get

failed to load TLS certificates

This command works fine in several other boxes. I suspect either something wrong with this specific certificate generation or missing root certificates (possibly being on different paths for this box?). Is there any source of additional logging or debugging info I could use to pinpoint the exact problem? Thanks,
filimon

Comment: Sure you have all the certificates required? There's a little bit about TLS at [KX.com](https://code.kx.com/platform/tls/) if you haven't seen it already.

Comment: I would also try comparing all of the relevant environment variables from the machines that work to the one that doesn't, see https://code.kx.com/q/kb/ssl/#tls-server-mode